# Oribatida masking question

Tags: algorithm-design, authenticated-encryption, sponge

Why [Oribatida](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jmc-2020-0018/pdf) uses previous capacity $V_{a+m-1}$ instead of current capacity $V_{a+m}$ for rate masking?

Answer (score 1):

This question drew my attention to the design of ["Schwaemm and Esch: Lightweight Authenticated Encryption and Hashing using the Sparkle Permutation Family"](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Lightweight-Cryptography/documents/round-1/spec-doc/SPARKLE-spec.pdf). In the enhanced sponge-based design, they incorporated a portion of rate whitening. However, this aspect is not accounted for in the security analysis, as it may be regarded as part of the underlying permutation.

Returning to your question, why is the current capacity not utilized for rate masking? It could be considered a component of the underlying permutation and thus not included in the security analysis.

Comment: Rate whitening is applied to rate, while Oribatida applies masking on ciphertext only (rate is not changed).